# Proper way to hide calendar icon (suffix icon) in DatePicker for AntD

Tags: reactjs, antd

This is the way I am hiding the calender icon in the DatePicker component for antD React. It feels hacky, is it the only way?

Attribute:

```
suffixIcon={<div></div>}
```

Full Component:

```
<DatePicker 
  bordered={false} 
  format="MMM Do, YYYY" 
  defaultValue={new moment()} 
  allowClear={false} 
  suffixIcon={<div></div>} 
/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try pass null to attribute

```
suffixIcon={null}
```

component props example:

```
<DatePicker
 suffixIcon={null} 
 bordered={false} 
 format="MMM Do, YYYY" 
 defaultValue={new moment()} 
 allowClear={false} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very late still, you can do like:

```
.ant-input-suffix {display: none;}
```

Comment: This is useful for hiding it on certain screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

In DatePicker, there are two things:

1. Calendar Icon, which is shown by default. (Highlighted in red square box).  [image: DatePicker Calendar Icon]
2. Cross Icon, which is shown once the date is selected and on Hover. (Highlighted below) [image]

---

#### Solution to hide Calendar Icon

To Hide Calendar Icon, add the following code snippet as an attribute to DatePicker component.

```
suffixIcon={null}
```

Example:

```
<DatePicker 
  suffixIcon={null}
  ..more Attributes 
/>
```

---

#### Solution to hide Cross Icon

To hide Cross Icon, add the following code snippet in the corresponding CSS file.

```
.ant-picker-clear{
  .anticon-close-circle{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide calendar icon

```
<DatePicker suffixIcon={null} />
```

To hide cross icon, you can pass the prop allowClear.

```
<DatePicker allowClear={false} />
```